# How do I abstract my business logic and object defintions away from my database access code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm

So I have a database with 2 tables - Workflows and WorkflowSteps I want to use the rows stored there to create objects in java BUT the catch is that I want to have my database code separated from my application code. From one point onwards - when Workflow/WorkflowSteps objects are create the rest of the application will not have to worry about DB access. So here is what I have:

```
public Workflow getPendingWorkflowId() {
    int workflowid = -1;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM xxx.workflows WHERE status = 'NOT-YET-STARTED' LIMIT 1");

        while (rs.next()) {
            workflowid = rs.getInt("id");
        }

        statement.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBAccessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error fetching workflows id");
    }

    return new Workflow(workflowid);
}
```

Each workflow object has a List to store the steps that pertain to a particular Workflow and then each WorkflowStep has a Map which is used to store data taken from a 3rd table:

```
public List<WorkflowStep> getUnworkedStepsByWFId(int id) {

    //can be changed
    ArrayList<WorkflowStep> steps = new ArrayList<WorkflowStep>();
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `workflow_steps` WHERE `workflow_id` =" + id + " AND status =  'NOT-YET-STARTED'");

        while (rs.next()) {

            steps.add(new WorkflowStep(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4)));

        }

        statement.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBAccessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error fetching workflows id");
    }

    return steps;
}
```

And here is the query for the 3rd table: 
    public Map getParametersForStep(int workflowId, int workstepPos) {

```
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();

        //MIGHT BE WRONG
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT wf.id AS workflowID, ws_steps.id AS workflowStepsID, name, param_value, pathname FROM workflows AS wf INNER JOIN workflow_steps AS ws_steps ON wf.id = ws_steps.workflow_id INNER JOIN ws_parameters ON ws_parameters.ws_id = ws_steps.id INNER JOIN submodule_params ON submodule_params.id = ws_parameters.sp_id AND wf.id =" + workflowId + " AND ws_steps.workflow_position =" + workstepPos);
        String paramName = null;
        String paramValue = null;

        while (rs.next()) {

            paramName = rs.getString("name");

            if (rs.getString("param_value") == null) {
                paramValue = rs.getString("pathname");
            } else {
                paramValue = rs.getString("param_value");
            }

            hMap.put(paramName, paramValue);
        }

        statement.close();
        rs.close();
        return hMap;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBAccessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error fetching workflow step parameters names");
    }

    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

Having this code in mind I end up with the following "procedure" to initialize a Workflow with all its WorkflowSteps and their Parameters:

```
Workflow wf = db.getPendingWorkflowId();
wf.initSteps(db.getUnworkedStepsByWFId(wf.getId()));
Iterator<WorkflowStep> it = wf.getSteps();

     while(it.hasNext()) {
         WorkflowStep step = it.next();             
         step.setParameters(db.getParametersForStep(wf.getId(), step.getPosInWorkflow()));
     }
```

I think I have a good level of decoupling but I wonder if this can be refactored somehow - for example probably move the step.setParameters  to a method of the WorkflowStep class but then I would have to pass a reference to the database connection (db) to a WorkflowStep object but in my view this will break the decoupling? So how would you people refactor this code?

Comment: This doesn't really deserve the -1.  It may have originally had a poorly worded title, but the fact remains that if you're not familiar with ORM already, then you should be able to ask a question like this and receive the answer 'use ORM'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are rolling your own [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). My suggestion would be to use one of existing ones like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Comment: I use MyBatis, but Hibernate def seems to be the popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function of an [Object Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  It serves to abstract your DB access away from your business model.  In fact, used properly, an ORM library allows you to write no database code at all.